# Find number of $x$, $3^x+5^x+7^x+11^x+13^x+17^x+19^x+23^x+25^x+29^x+31^x+35^x+37^x$ is prime.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the number of positive integer $x$ less than $2014$ for which

$3^x+5^x+7^x+11^x+13^x+17^x+19^x+23^x+25^x+29^x+31^x+35^x+37^x$ is prime.

I've tried to solve this problem but don't know where to start, please suggest.

Comment: "Hint"?${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a solution since x must be a positive integer.

Comment: @Arthur As commented, it is not a solution. Second, if we want *the number of solutions*, then giving out one of them is not a hint **unless** from it we can deduce something about that number of solutions...

Comment: Hint: think modulo 3.

Comment: Possibly a hint: $3$ is always a divisor, for positive $x$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm assuming you must split x into cases of odd and even?

Comment: @DonAntonio Moo has claimed that $x=0$ is the *only integer* that makes the expression prime.

Comment: @EclipseSun - The comment was edited. The `There are no other...` part was added later.

Comment: @gandalf61 So I guess the lesson here is that whenever you have numbers raised to an unknown power, it's always a good idea to consider it mod 3, because everything is either 0, 1, -1 mod 3, which is easy to raise to powers, right? Is this how you came to the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from $3^x$, there are $6$ pairs of the form $(6n-1)^x+(6n+1)^x$.

If $x$ is even, these are all $1 \mod 3$ so their sum is divisible by $3$.

If $x$ is odd, each pair is $(-1)+1=0 \mod 3$, so the sum is again divisible by $3$.

Note that, for any prime $p$,
this works for
$p^x$ plus $kp$ pairs of
$(mp-1)^x+(mp+1)^x$.

Comment: There does not exist $x$ satisfied the condition, thank you very much, everyone.